# Multiple instances of a vuex module still share the same state?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

[According to the docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#module-reuse), if I simply return the state as a function, I should be able to reuse the store module. However, when I did this, my vuex store module still shared state across all the component instances.

Here's the component markup:

```html
<template>
    <button class="button" type="button" @click="onClick">{{ count }}</button>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapState, mapMutations} from 'vuex';

    export default {
        name: 'sub-component',
        computed: {
            ...mapState('myModule', ['count'])
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapMutations('myModule', ['INCREMENT_COUNT']),

            onClick() {
                this.INCREMENT_COUNT();
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Here's my store module:

```js
const namespaced = true;

const state = () => {
    return {
        count: 0
    };
};

const mutations = {
    INCREMENT_COUNT(state) {
        state.count++;
    },
};

export default {
    namespaced,
    state,
    mutations
};
```

So, in my parent component, I have an arbitrary number of "sub-component" (button) instances. When I click, it does increment, but it increments for all of the instances. Is there a way to still utilize Vuex store without sharing the state across all the instances of my sub-component?

*Context:* I'm using Vuex in a SPA -- so a standard use-case for managing the state/methods across components in SPA. But I also have deeply nested components that interact and update other components in the SPA (but these other components need to maintain to their own state). Yes, I don't have to use Vuex, but it seemed like it would be cleaner.

Comment: "Is there a way to still utilize Vuex store without sharing the state across all the instances of my sub-component" - yes. Do not use Vuex for these components. What you want defies the point of using it. It's unclear what's your case, consider explaining it instead of focusing on potentially wrong way to solve it, it could be XY problem

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm using Vuex in a SPA -- so a standard use-case for managing the state/methods across components in SPA. But I also have deeply nested components that interact and update other components in the SPA (but these other components need to maintain to their own state). Yes, I don't have to use Vuex, but it seemed like it would be cleaner.

Comment: @EstusFlask Also, [what do docs mean](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#module-reuse) then when they say "Module Reuse"? I thought when the docs say "multiple instances of a module" they meant the the state is _not_ shared between instances.

Comment: The reuse means that you can have `moduleA: myModule, moduleB: myModule` in a store. It's still global. As I said, it's XY problem. Consider reasking with a focus on your actual case instead of potentially wrong solution. "But I also have deeply nested components that interact and update other components in the SPA" - probably local state with provide/inject, or vuex dynamic modules or state subtrees, or else.